# derivative in two variables.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-operators

Suppose we are doing two-variable calculus in $x,y$. Let $t=x+y$, and I would like to know how to calculate $\partial/\partial t$.

We know that $\partial t/\partial x=\partial t/\partial y = 1$. Using multivariable chain rule,
$${\partial f\over \partial t} = {\partial f\over \partial x}{\partial x\over \partial t}+{\partial f\over \partial y}{\partial y\over \partial t} = {\partial f\over \partial x}+{\partial f\over \partial y}\tag{$*$}$$
However
$${\partial (x^2-y^2)\over \partial t}={\partial t(x-y)\over \partial t}=x-y \tag{$**$}$$
while using ($*$) we would get $2x-2y$. So clearly something is wrong here...

My question is, what would be the correct way to write $\partial/\partial t$ in terms of $\partial_x$ and $\partial_y$?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ by itself makes no sense. YOu need to fix another function to make up a complete coordinate system. For example, if you work in the coordinate system $(t,x)$ vs $(t,y)$ or some other willy-wonka system, you’ll get different answers. See [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/790971/203278) for the explanation in the (unfortunately complicated) blackhole scenario (and in the sublink, in a thermodynamic setting). But really although I phrase them in these settings, the underlying issue is one of multivariable calculus, so it (should hopefully) be understandable.

Comment: In the calculation (**), Please explain how you got from the first expression [i.e. what you are trying to calculate] to the next one. In the next one there is ∂t in both numerator and denominator, which makes little sense, and somehow $x^2-y^2$ has been replaced by $x-y$ . Why?

Comment: @peek-a-boo ∂/∂t is often used as an operator, so I would not say it makes no sense.

Comment: @coffeemath In (**), since $t= x+y$, I am using $x^2+y^2=(x+y)(x-y)=t(x-y)$.

Comment: @coffeemath yes ultimately it should be a differential operator which is a $C^{\infty}(\Bbb{R}^2)$-linear combination of our usual $\partial_x,\partial_y$. But *which one*? Writing merely $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$, without any further explanation leaves this completely ambiguous, so I still maintain it makes no sense (until one is more specific so as to give it a meaning).

Comment: @peek-a-boo I see. So in (**) I am actually using the coordinate system $(x+y,x-y)$.

Comment: Why "infinitely many" variables in the title?

Comment: I was also wondering why the title says "infinitely many" when the question is just about two variables.

Comment: changed the title :)

Answer (score 1):

*This is a community answer, expanding the discussion from the comments. Please feel free to improve it to your liking!*

The very first thing to remember is that a partial derivative is well-defined only after one fixes a coordinate system, because partial derivatives are coefficients appearing when expanding the differential form $\mathrm{d}f$ in a coordinate system:

$$ \mathrm{d}f = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{\partial f}{\partial x_i} \mathrm{d}x_i $$

This tells that the partial derivatives are "linearly dependent" in some sense, and so, each of the partial derivatives *does depend on* the choice of the coordinate system. Let us demonstrate this using OP's example.

**Example 1.** Let $f = x^2 - y^2$, and choose the coordinate system $(t, s) = (x + y, x - y)$. Then

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t}(st) = s = x - y. $$

**Example 2.** Still let $f = x^2 - y^2$, but now choose the coordinate system $(t, x) = (x + y, x)$. Then

$$ \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} t(2x-t) = 2x - 2t = -2y. $$